# как ограничить доступ для др стран через nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, geoip

нужно ограничить доступ к сайту с определенных стран при помощи nginx и GeoIP модуля

дело в том, что мы работаем с платформой и nginx там уже настроен из коробки, но блокировать можно только лишь встроенными средствами платформы и лишь отдельные части сайта. хотелось бы как-то централизованно сделать.

используем убунту 12.04, может есть какие-нибудь другие способы программной блокировки доступа?

Comment: Гуглите по "nginx geoip reject country". Ответов хватает.

Answer (score 2):

У вас уже задана переменная [geoip_country](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html#geoip_country)? Она задаётся в блоке `http` и указывает путь к файлу - базе данных GeoIP. Если это уже настроили, то можете использовать переменные `$geoip_country_code` и `$geoip_country_code` которые возвращают двух и трёхбуквенные коды стран. Далее будет удобно использовать директиву `map`, в том же блоке `http`, примерно таки образом:

```
map $geoip_country_code $you_shall_not_pass {
   default yes;
   RU no;
   BY no;
   KZ no;
}
```

В данном варианте если переменная `$geoip_country_code` имеет значения `RU`, `BY`, `KZ`, то переменная `$you_shall_not_pass` примет значение `no`. Во всех остальных случаях - `yes`.

Теперь в блоке `server` нужного сайта можно написать в определённом `location` такое ограничение:

```
if ($you_shall_not_pass = yes) {
  return 444;
}
```

Т. е. если переменная `$you_shall_not_pass` имеет значение `yes`, т. е. код странны не относится к разрешённым и запрос не должен пройти, то он... не проходит. Как поменять конфигурацию для варианта если по-умолчанию нужно разрешение, а запрет - для перечисленных стран, объяснять, полагаю, не нужно.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то в конфиге мне нужно создать location / и добавить туда условие if?

Comment: @ДаниилГетьманцев зависит от того, какую именно часть сайта вы хотите закрыть. Весь, или, например, только админку... Если весь, то да - это должно быть в `location /`.

Comment: странно, при попытке инициализации переменной в nginx.conf бьет ошибку и ссылается на unknown directive $geoip_country, я так понимаю, что это свидетельствует о том, что модуль не подключен.

nginx -V показывает, что в модуль --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic установлен. Не могу понять, в чем может быть затык. Могут ли права доступа (www-data, 755) к файлу GeoIP.dat каким-то образом повлиять на процесс инициализации переменной?

Comment: файл попросту не считывается и сравнение по стране не происходит..

Comment: @ДаниилГетьманцев: загрузите динамический модуль такой командой: `load_module "modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";`. Это делается в блоке `main`. http://serverfault.com/questions/797850/unknown-directive-geoip-country-on-nginx-1-10-1#797851

Comment: подключил модуль
объявил командой 
geoip_country   /etc/nginx/GeoIPv6.dat;

Решение рабочее, спасибо за помощь.